# Gerrit slaves to use local DB

Tags: git, gerrit

Is there a way for Gerrit instances running as slaves to use a local database rather than using the master Gerrit database, so the the authorization happens quicker.

Can someone throw some light if there an already available method to do this with MySQL and Gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a slave mysql server on your gerrit slave server and update the gerrit.config to point to this local mysql server:

```
[database]

  type = MYSQL

  hostname = localhost

  database = reviewdb #database name

  username = gerrit2 

  password = s3kr3t
```

Procedure to setup the Mysql Slave: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-setup-slaves.html